# Directory suggestions on Vim status line

Tags: vim, vimrc

Recently I came across the following in a video about Vim: typing Tab in the command line in vim makes the status line show you suggestions on the possible directories matching the letters you typed so far (see attached). Does anyone know which Vim plugin or setting lets you do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option you want is:

```
:set wildmenu
```

You will need to add the command to your vimrc to make it permanent.  See:

```
:help 'wildmenu'
```